# Transform a GADT without constraints to another GADT with constraints when such constraints hold

Tags: haskell, dsl, gadt

Can we transform a GADT without a given constraint on its constructors to a GADT that does have the said constraint? I want to do this because I want to get a deep-embedding of Arrows and do some interesting things with the representation that (for now) seem to require `Typeable`. ([One reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12232127/682376))

```
data DSL a b where
  Id   :: DSL a a
  Comp :: DSL b c -> DSL a b -> DSL a c
  -- Other constructors for Arrow(Loop,Apply,etc)

data DSL2 a b where
  Id2   :: (Typeable a, Typeable b)             => DSL2 a a
  Comp2 :: (Typeable a, Typeable b, Typeable c) => DSL2 b c -> DSL2 a b -> DSL2 a c
  -- ...
```

We could try the following `from` function but that breaks quickly as we don't have the
`Typeable` information for the recursive point

```
from :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) =>  DSL a b -> DSL2 a b
from (Id)       = Id2
from (Comp g f) = Comp2 (from g) (from f)
```

So instead we try to capture the transformation in a type class. However, that will break as well as we will be missing the `Typeable b` information as `b` is an existential.

```
class From a b where
  from :: a -> b

instance (Typeable a, Typeable b) => From (DSL a b) (DSL2 a b) where
  from (Id)       = Id2
  from (Comp g f) = Comp2 (from g) (from f)
```

Any other suggestions? Ultimately I want to create a deep-embedding of `Category` and `Arrow` together with `Typeable` information on the type parameters. This is so I can use the arrow-syntax to construct a value in my DSL and have fairly standard Haskell code. Maybe I have to resort to Template Haskell?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem with the recursive case is fatal to transforming `DSL a b` into `DSL2 a b`.

To do this transformation would require finding the `Typeable` dictionary for the existential type `b` in the `Comp` case - but what `b` actually is has already been forgotten.

For example consider the following program:

```
data X = X Int
-- No Typeable instance for X

dsl1 :: DSL X Char
dsl1 = -- DSL needs to have some way to make non-identity terms,
       -- use whatever mechanism it offers for this.

dsl2 :: DSL Int X
dsl2 = -- DSL needs to have some way to make non-identity terms,
       -- use whatever mechanism it offers for this.

v :: DSL Int Char
v = Comp dsl1 dsl2

v2 :: DSL2 Int Char
v2 = -- made by converting v from DSL to DSL2, note that Int and Char are Typeable

typeOfIntermediate :: DSL a c -> TypeRep
typeOfIntermediate int =
    case int of
        Comp (bc :: DSL2 b c) (ab :: DSL2 a b) ->
            typeOf (undefined :: b)

typeOfX = typeOfIntermediate v2
```

In other words if there was a way to do the conversion in general, you could somehow invent a `Typeable` instance for a type that doesn't actually have one.

Comment: In ghc 7.8 every type will have a typeable instance automatically derived by the compiler, so that obstacle will no longer apply.  In fact I believe that feature is in the current 7.7 HEAD so the restriction no longer applies to those Willing to brave building ghc from source

Comment: But even in GHC 7.8 no information whatsoever will be available for an existential type.

Comment: For the new feature in GHC 7.8, it's important that although every concrete type would be Typeable, you wouldn't be able to assume Typeable for a /polymorphic/ variable - so for example the only total function of type (a -> a) would still have to be the identity function. Otherwise we'd lose parametricity. It does make my specific counter-argument invalid, though.

Answer (score 3):

> Ultimately I want to create a deep-embedding of `Category` and `Arrow` together with `Typeable` information on the type parameters. This is so I can use the arrow-syntax to construct a value in my DSL and have fairly standard Haskell code.

Perhaps you should resort to [`{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#rebindable-syntax) (while noting that it implies `NoImplicitPrelude`). Create your own `arr`, `(>>>)`, `first`, `app`, `(|||)` and `loop` functions and GHC will use them when desugaring arrow notation, instead of the standard versions from Control.Arrow.

The manual states that *“the types of these functions must match the Prelude types very closely”*. If you're building a parallel class hierarchy (a copy of the hierarchy in Control.Arrow but with `Typeable` constraints added to the type signatures) you should be fine.

(n.b. I am not familiar with arrow notation so have never used it in conjunction with RebindableSyntax; my answer is an intelligent guess.)

Comment: Ah, somehow it slipped into my mind that `RebindableSyntax` did not work for Arrows. I'll try to work around the issue this way. Thank you.

Comment: I have [tried](https://gist.github.com/spockz/a241aba85e37f04ce5a1) it  . But it seems that somehow we still end up with the original arrow functions...