# Prove that a constraint holds for a component of a product from the fact it holds for the product

Tags: haskell, typeclass, gadt, constraint-kinds

I have a class `C` with instances for one type and for tuples.

```
class C a

instance C Int

instance (C a, C b) => C (a, b)
```

Using the normal `Dict` GADT for capturing constraints

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

data Dict c where
    Dict :: c => Dict c
```

is it possible to prove `C a` from `C (a, b)`?

```
fstDict :: Dict (C (a, b)) -> Dict (C a)
fstDict Dict = ???
```

I suspect the immediate answer is "no" since `fstDict Dict = Dict` isn't sufficient, and there are few other possibilities. Is there any way to change `C` so that constraints for components of products can be recovered from the constraint on the product?

I am, perhaps incorrectly, trying to accomplish the same thing as [the most closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717462/transform-a-gadt-without-constraints-to-another-gadt-with-constraints-when-such), however I have the luxury to demand a `Dict` from one or both ends of the category.

```
data DSL a b where
    DSL :: (Dict C a -> DSL' a b) -> DSL a b

data DSL' a b where
    DSL' :: (C a, C b) => ... -> DSL' a b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An open variant of [Daniel Wagner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27853111/414413) would use a `TypeFamily` to let each type that implements the class specify a context that it needs.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)
import Data.Proxy

data Dict c where
    Dict :: c => Dict c
```

The class lets each type specify an additional constraint `Ctx a` that the type needs. The `cdict` function forces the context to follow from `C` and provides a way to get at underlying  `Ctx`s without including them in the `Ctx` for e.g. products.

```
class C a where
    type Ctx a :: Constraint
    cdict :: Proxy a -> CDict a
```

A `CDict` is then a `Dict` that holds both the constraint `C a` and also whatever additional context `Ctx a` the type `a` needs

```
type CDict a = Dict (C a, Ctx a)
```

The `Int` instance doesn't need any extra context

```
instance C Int where
    type Ctx Int = ()
    cdict _ = Dict
```

The tuple instance needs both `C a` and `C b`

```
instance (C a, C b) => C (a, b) where
    type Ctx (a, b) = (C a, C b)
    cdict _ = Dict
```

We can write `fstCDict` for tuples.

```
fstCDict :: forall a b. CDict (a, b) -> CDict a
fstCDict Dict = case cdict (Proxy :: Proxy a) of Dict -> Dict
```

#### Incorrect instance

If we try to write an incorrect instance of `C` that magically summons `Show` instances

```
instance (C a) => C (Maybe a) where
    type Ctx (Maybe a) = (C a, Show a)
    cdict _ = Dict
```

It results in a compiler error

```
    Could not deduce (Show a) arising from a use of `Dict'
    from the context (C a)
      bound by the instance declaration ...
    Possible fix:
      add (Show a) to the context of the instance declaration
    In the expression: Dict
    In an equation for `cdict': cdict _ = Dict
    In the instance declaration for `C (Maybe a)'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to store all ancestor dictionaries in your `Dict` type:

```
data CDict a where
    IntDict :: C Int => CDict Int
    PairDict :: C (a, b) => CDict a -> CDict b -> CDict (a, b)

fstCDict :: CDict (a, b) -> CDict a
fstCDict (PairDict fst snd) = fst
```

This has the downside that you must make the `CDict` type reflect the structure of your instances.